# Problems with compilation of project

Tags: java, maven, javafx-11

When I change jdk from 8 to 11 I cought this promlem when I try to compile my project.

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  17.012 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-08-21T14:09:01+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project desktop-client: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /E:/cryptoterminal/usr_desktop-client/src/main/java/com/exs/desktop/cryptoterminal/controls/SystemButton.java:[3,42] package com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom is not visible
[ERROR]   (package com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom is declared in module java.xml, which does not export it)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
PS E:\cryptoterminal\usr_desktop-client>
```

The package com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom; is package source of javafx located in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\lib

Comment: You should _never_ directly use `com.sun.*` packages (or more specifically the classes within). Those could removed in any future Java versions and thus access is restricted on purpose.

Comment: Thanks I will use import org.w3c.dom.Attr; instead com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom;